# libpqxx throws an exception during DEBUG mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, postgresql-9.2, libpqxx

I have a **MFC** project that uses libpqxx. All settings are default.

Release mode is working properly as i expected. But when i switch to Debug mode, it shows an exception and says Debug Assertion:

The most interesting thing is, If I use Shared DLL instead of Static (on Debug of course) it works!

Basicaly, Debug with Static Library shows this exception/error. If i switch to Shared DLL it works again. Of course i can use shared as debug and static as release but **Is this the right thing**?

Note: This project is base and fresh. I did not changed any config from Configuratrion Manager.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Shared Debug DLL - how and what? You mean MFC or ATL?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. Yes, MFC. I updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I am not sure if `libpqxx` uses MFC or not (and which one?). I suspect that you are allocating some memory from one heap, and de-allocating it from another heap. Mixing MFC versions, as well as Static/non-Static mixture of MFC will cause this assertion.

Do not treat it as *working* on Release build! It is just not defending itself (i.e. now showing any assertion message). Your best bet is to locate the cause of this problem, and first one goes by looking-up the call stack (hit Retry on this assertion dialog).

See, if `libpqxx` depends on MFC, or it disallws mixing Static version of MFC. You can either see the documentation of `libpqxx`, and/or use Dependency Walker to see if library is using MFC.

Comment: `...as well as Static/non-Static mixture of MFC will cause this assertion...` i finally choose another library file called libpqxxd.lib and woala :) It just works. I just mixture things.

Comment: BTW, it is not for MFC directly. Because in MFC it shows an error "null": identifier not found. But standardWin32 project builds fine. I still don't know how to pass null error.